# All scheduled actions are pending in Wordpress with FPM in docker

Tags: wordpress

I'm running Wordpress 6.3.2 in Docker container (`wordpress:6.3.2-fpm`).

When I go to Action scheduler - all the actions are pending (they were pending for months, before I deleted them).

When I try to start them manually - they just work.

I've tried to run `WP-Crontrol`, but it says:

```
Unexpected HTTP response code: 403
```

What can I do with it to make it work? Does it mean that I don't have crond to run those action periodically?